# How can I visualize the execution of RxJava graphs?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Suppose I have some complex chains of `Single`, `Maybe` and `Observable` objects that perform some tasks.

For example:

```
// Download, unzip and parse a release
public static Single<Release> fetchRelease(final Release release) {
    final Path cachePath = getCachePath(release);
    return download(release.url, cachePath, true).ignoreElements()
        .andThen(hash(cachePath))
        .flatMap(fileHash -> unzip(cachePath)
            .andThen(parseFile(unzipTargetPath)));
}
```

These chains might be run across several threads.

**The problem is that I would like to render the progress of these tasks to the user, without muddying their logic where possible.**

For example, the above task might show:

```
+-Fetching release 1.0... Done
  +-Downloading https://www.example.com/v1.0.0.zip 100%
  +-Hashing Library/Caches/Example/v1.0.0.zip... Done
  +-Unpacking Library/Caches/Example/v1.0.0.zip
    +-src.. Done
    +-tests... Done
    +-resources... Done
  +-Parsing release... Done
```

Ideally, I would also like to display the heirarchy of tasks. This is currently only encoded in the Java call graph.

My current thinking is:

- Change every `Single` to an `Observable`, where the last element is the result and the others are progress updates.
- Write event classes for each stage of the task.

I think this will be make the code less readable and lead to lots of boiler-plate.

```
public final class DownloadProgress {
    public final float progress;
    // etc..
}

// etc... 

public final class FetchReleaseProgress {
    public final Variant<DownloadProgress, HashingProgress, UnpackProgress, ParseProgress> progress;
    // etc...
}
```

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: you can look into htrace

Comment: use the RxJavaPlugin

Answer (score 0):

you're on the right way, you can write a full ui model that represents the ui events that you're interested in, I'll take your case here as an example

```
+-Fetching release 1.0... Done
  +-Downloading https://www.example.com/v1.0.0.zip 100%
  +-Hashing Library/Caches/Example/v1.0.0.zip... Done
  +-Unpacking Library/Caches/Example/v1.0.0.zip
    +-src.. Done
    +-tests... Done
    +-resources... Done
  +-Parsing release... Done
```

and the model could be somthing like that:

```
final class DownloadUiModel {
private float progress;
private String hashing;
private String downloading;
private String unpacking;
private String done;

private DownloadUiModel(float progress, String hashing //..etc) {
}
//getters
//setters
}
```

then in with Rxjava could you will use the previous model as follow:

```
download(release.url, cachePath, true)
.ignoreElements()
.map(response -> downloadUiModel.setDownloading(release.url))
.andThen(hash(cachePath))
.map(response -> downloadUiModel.setHashing(cachePath))
.flatMap(fileHash -> unzip(cachePath)
.andThen(parseFile(unzipTargetPath)))
.map(response -> downloadUiModel.setUnzipping(unzipTargetPath))
...
```

then when subscribing, you can use this ui model to update you ui like so

```
downloadObservable.subscribe(model -> 
if(model.getProgress()!= 100){
Timber.d(model.getDownloading())
Timber.d(model.getHashing())
Timber.d(model.getUnpacking))
//...
}
```

the nice part about this way that your ui logic is seperated from your request logic, and you can easly switch to Android main thread safely.